# Angular js :file upload in background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, file-upload

We have a long form with more than 20 fields so breakdown into three pages

in the first page there is a file upload is present so when user navigate to second page i want to continue the upload of file

code:

```
//first page 
controller('FirstController',function($scope){

   //do file upload here
  $scope.uploadFile = function(){


    }
})
//on navigate to second page load this controller
controller('SecondController',function($scope){

   //update profile info here
   $scope.ProfileInfo = function(user){


   }

});
```

Comment: You can't because when state changed `FirstController` will be close, so you have to make user wait on upload complete

Comment: So there is no another way??

Comment: You can insert your upload function in you main layout and connect it to your main controller which when states change, function still work.

Comment: What you mean by main layout??

Comment: When you create a `angular.app` with `ng-route` or `ui-route` you will have a main layout which include with `ng-view` or `ui-view`, you should insert your upload input in it, because when you change the state it not change.

Comment: But the problem it doesn't have router